# getting error for codes from handling form submission guide (Spring Getting Started Guide)

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I was following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) getting started guide and following error:

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 10, col 31)"

The code is exactly same as shown in the guide. I understand this is something to do with Thymeleaf form tag, so I also checked the [Thymeleaf documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form) but couldn't figure out what is wrong with my code.

Here's the code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Form</h1>
  <form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

GreetingController.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
        return "result";
    }
}
```

Greeting.java

```
package com.example;

public class Greeting {

    private long id;
    private String content;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So tutorial says you to create 2 files, `result.html` and `greeting.html`. And you created `index.html`. The thing is that you didn't bind your template page to Spring controller, it's bound to `greeting.html` as in tuturial.

So solution is just to change return from **greeting** to **index** in `greetingForm()` method:

```
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public String greetingForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
    return "index"; // <- changed line
}
```

Hope this would help you.